# proof that a finite bounded set converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm having trouble understanding the part of the solution below which proves that every bounded sequence that's finite converges, which comes from theorom 3.8 (chapter title: "numerical sequences and Series") of "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by rudin.  The theorem basically states that every bounded sequence contains a convergent subsequence.

My interpetation is that $E$ is bounded but $\left\{s_n\right\}$ is not.  So we just assume that $\left\{s_n\right\}$ continues to take inputs.  Visually.  I see this as a parabola where $z$ is some point on one side of the maxima thus the subsequence includes the point on the other side which takes on the same value in the range?

btw, $E$ refers to the range of $\left\{s_n\right\}$

> If $E$ is finite, then then there is at least one point of $E$, say $z$, and a sequence $\left\{n_k\right\}$ where $n_1<n_2<...$, such that $s_{n_1}=s_{n_2}=...z$.  The subsquence $\left\{s_{n_k}\right\}$ obtained in this manner evidently converges

Comment: But how can I be sure that $n>k$?

Comment: The proof just says that if you start to pick a random sequence out of finite set, you will inevitably have some member repeated infinitely many times. If this was not the case, the sequence was not infinite to begin with, since number of terms is bounded by $|E|m$ where $m$ is maximum number of repetitions

Comment: Note.  That's actually th 3.6.

Comment: A sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ of members of $E$ can be defined as a function $f:\mathbb  N\to E,$ where $  x_n=f(n).$  If $E$ is finite and non-empty there must exist $x\in E$ such that $\{n:x_n=x\}=\{n:f(n)=x\}$ is an infinite set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a collection of infinitely-many elements with only finitely-many distinct ones, there must be, for cardinality reasons, at least one, say $s_k$ that repeats infinitely often. Then the subsequence given by $s_k,s_k,....,s_k,..$ is constant and therefore convergent.

Comment: So must I assume $\left\{s_n\right\}$ is infinite?

Comment: @johnfowles You cannot talk about "convergence of finite sequence" in a meaningful way

Comment: @user160738  This was a great comment!  Thanks so much!

Comment: @johnfowles: Yes, a sequence, by definition/construction is indexed by the Natural numbers. So we have a collection $s_1, s_2, s_3,....$ but only finitely-many distinct ones.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some fundamental misconceptions.

A sequence is an countably infinite list of elements.  That's it.  As they are countably infinite, the terms be indexed by the natural numbers. So we may write the sequence as $\{s_n\}$.  These $n$ or simply a means of indexing.  They aren't really "input" in the way you are thinking for them.  (However as there is an indexing mapping from $n \rightarrow s_n$, I can't really say they *aren't* input either.)

Unlike a conventional set the the terms of a sequence may repeat and need not be distinct.  If we want to discuss the distinct points of the sequence we call that set the range.  It is just a set of distinct points.

The intuitive meaning that a sequence is bounded is that there are $M$ and $N$ so that all the $s_n$ are $M \le s_n \le N$.  However this is not an acceptable definition as this implies the $s_n$ are real numbers rather than generic points in a metric space.  Instead the proper definition is the distance between any two is less than or equal to some real $M$.  I.e. for any two $s_i, s_j$ then $d(s_i, s_j) \le M$ for some $M$.  Another way of saying the exact some thing is that the distance from any term and some "origin" point in the space, is less than some $M$.  i.e. for some point $q$ and any $s_i$ then $d(s_i,q) \le M$ for some $M$.

It's impossible for the range to be bounded and the sequence not, or vice versa, because the range and the sequences consist of the exact same elements.  The only difference is the in the sequence the terms are indexed in a specific order whereas the range is simply a shopping bag of the distinct terms.

This has nothing to do with visualizing as a parabola.  It's simply an infinite list of terms, all of them within some distance of an origin point.  The sequence need not follow any pattern.  It can hop around like a flea.

HOWEVER

the theorem $3.6$ says that for any bounded sequence $\{s_n\}$ has a subsequence $\{p_n\}$ that *doesn't* hop around but that converges to a point $p$.

In other words: Even if a bounded sequence hops around, we can always pick some points in order, so that the points we pick converge to a point $p$.

Pf:  If the $\{s_n\}$ only has a finite number of distinct terms then at least one of the terms (call it $p$_ must be repeated infinitely often.  In this case just pick the infinite reiteration of the repeated term to be get a sequence that ends with an infinite repetition of $p$.  $\{......., p,p,p,p,.....\}$.  This converges to $p$.

That's all the argument is saying.

So that is the answer to your question.

But that was the *easy* case.  The rest of the proof is the meat.

If there are an infinite number of distinct points of $\{s_n\}$ then let  $E$ be  the set of distinct points.  ALthough infinite this set is bounded (as they are the same points as the sequence) and so it has a limit point $p$ (this is theorem 2.28).  Let $B_n(p)$ be the points, $x$ of $E$ so that $d(p,x)< \frac 1n$.  By theorem 2.20 this neighbor hood has an infinite number of points. Let $s_{n}$ be one of the points in $B_n(p)$. We'll let $p_1 = s_{n}$ be our first term of the subsequence.

$B_2(p)$ has an infinite number of points.  So we'll select one, $s_m$ that is further down the sequence than $s_n$ was.  We'll let $p_2 = s_{m}$ be our second term of the subsequence.

We repeat that indefinitely. For each $n$ we pick a point $p_n= s_{foo}$ in $B_n(p)$ so that $s_{foo}$ is further along in the sequence than $p_{n-1}$ was.

We will end up with a subsequence $\{p_n\}$ and as $d(p, p_n)  <  \frac 1n$ we have $\{p_n\}$ converges to $p$.

And that's it.